# how to print message on console by using custom annotations

Tags: java, maven, annotations

this is my code for project demo
[image]

all the code for project demo
[image]

then I run : mvn clean install and I got demo-0.0.1.jar

and in another project I import the demo-0.0.1.jar and make a test:

import com.company.annotation.Lock;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().test();
}

@Lock(name="test")
public void test(){
    System.out.println(1);
}
```

}

I hope it not noly print "1" but also print "I'm here",but the result is I only see "1",could you tell me how to print "I'm here"

Comment: don't post code as a picture... its text and can therefore also be pasted as that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.not super.init(processingEnv) it should be super.init(env)
2.if want see the console print should like: javac -cp demo-0.0.1.jar Test.java